# Which objects or materials are dangerous for rabbits?

Tags: rabbits

Imagine a small rabbit in a messy teenager bedroom.

Should I sweep the room for anything specific to reduce danger?

For example, any open containers with liquids that humans can not drink should be removed, I assume.
I was seriously worried about cigarettes or free tobacco in the ground - but I clarified that in an earlier question, it does not cause a significant risk.

For example, do any of the following pose a danger?

- knives
- razor blades
- large pieces of broken glass
- small sharp glass particles
- small hard and smooth objects
- open flames like candles
- hot objects like soldering irons
- ...

Of course I am mostly interested in the ones that do not come to my mind. I already learned that rabbits are pretty smart - so I would not be too surprised if almost nothing is dangerous for them.

Comment: I would assume that all you step in and it gets stuck would be dangerous. Like glass or razor blades. Knifes I think are less dangerous, if they are less sharp than the razor blades. Also if the rabbit is really hungry, it may cause trouble to nip on everything. And out of an reason nobody undertsands, rabbits like to chew on wires. So wires with electricity should not be reachable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure this is not a complete list but here goes:

- Rabbits will run and smash into stuff when they're playing.  They'll also start running and crashing into things when they're startled.  Don't leave anything around that you don't want them to run into.
- They will chew on whatever they feel like if they get it in their crazy little heads.  This means electric wires and toxic materials.  Even wires that won't electrocute them can be bad because you don't want them swallowing short sharp wire segments.  Things like pressure treated wood or cellophane aren't going to be good for them.  They'll handle a little but if they're just in the room and can chew on it whenever they like that can cause health problems.  Anything that has texture of "food" but is not digestible is bad for them (styrofoam, insulation, plastic bags)
- Many rabbit-edible foods are still bad for rabbits and should only be given in moderation.  Good example: carrots have too much sugar and they should only have small amounts.  They're not going to voluntarily avoid things like that.  Don't take chances with things like potato chips laying around on the floor (don't know how messy your teenager is).  If a rabbit regularly eats random junk food or bits of plastic it finds on the floor it won't die right away but it will eventually give it health problems and take years off its life.  Realistically, i wouldn't count on the rabbit not to eat a whole pack of cigarettes if it happens to find one and no one stops it.
- Many rabbits like heights and climb.  They are still rabbits and not cats so climbing is not their strength and landing is definitely a weakness.
- Rabbits will move objects around.  Sometimes by clawing at them, sometimes by picking them up with their teeth and throwing them.  If they try that with broken glass, razor blades, or knives, it won't go well.  They don't know that something is sharp.
- Rabbits like to knock things over.  I would not leave something that could start a fire (like a candle or a hot soldering iron) where they can reach them.

So yes, rabbits can be very smart in some ways but they're not nutritional experts, they don't know if an object is dangerous, they do get crazy sometimes, they can be hard to predict, and they can be clumsy and self-destructive.  Some of the screwed up things my rabbits have done:

- Run across the room full speed and body slam into a wall to stop.  Just because it's fun.
- Run around the perimeter of the room crashing into each corner when they're startled.
- Work hard to pull a data cable into their enclosure then chew through it.  This was at the age of 7 and never having an interest in wires before.
- Flop* off the edge of a shelf and fall hard on their side on the floor a foot below.
- Leap to the top of a 3 foot tall partition, balance like a cat for a short while, then leap off the other side.
- Leap off a waist-height shelf onto a flexible surface because they like the spring-board effect.

Your rabbit will probably be fine going around your teenager's room for a while but someone needs to be watching it.  If it starts chewing on a thing it shouldn't chew, stop it and take the thing away.  If it tries to get up where it shouldn't be, stop it and put it back on the floor.  The teenager probably wants to do that anyway unless she wants frayed edges on all her clothes, missing corners on all her books, and pee stains on her bed covers.

---

* if you don't know what a "flop" is or call it something else:  when a rabbit is feeling content, it might suddenly fall on its side and lay that way for a while.  Sometimes it seems like they're throwing themselves at the ground.

Comment: My rabbits live outaide in the garden. So running into things they do not do, because they have enough space to get their crazy 5 minutes... So this was not in my mind. Also in a room there is not this much distraction as outside, then rabbits make a lots of stuff to entertain themself +1

Comment: But one point, maybe useful: if you make the surfaces the rabbits climb onto and jump onto less slippery, the most of them can handle jumps down very well (of course you need to make jumps from unappropriate highs unpossible)

Comment: @Allerleirauh Didn't think modifying surfaces was an option since there's broken glass around.  Anyway, that would make it safer, yes, but a rabbit can't take a fall like a cat can so best to just avoid the heights. And if they start to lounge, they can roll off the edge.

Comment: The comment was not specific for this question. More for all people interested in this. My feeling would nit allow them to climb over one meter (big ones) or half a meter (small breeds). They enjoy to have a place to view the surrounding from :)